# Is Diet Coke 99% water?

Tags: nutrition, soda

I've come across the claim a few times that Diet Coke is 99% water.

Examples:

1. [RealAge - 8 Diet Coke Claims You'll Want to Know About](http://www.realage.com/food/8-diet-coke-claims-youll-want-to-know-about)
2. [Freakonomics - Diet Coke is 99% Water (And That Is Now a Good Thing)](http://www.freakonomics.com/2007/08/20/diet-coke-is-99-water-and-that-is-now-a-good-thing/)

Partial support for the claim seems to stem from the following advertisement, which seems to imply there is no major difference between Diet Coke and water.

Is this claim accurate?

Comment: I would think that just about any soft drink is at least 98% water by volume, but the 2% makes a difference— just like the 2% of DNA that separates humans and chimpanzees.

Comment: @Choster I don't find it hard to believe that they are mostly water, but I've encountered a lot of people who disagree, so am looking for some solid proof either way.

Comment: @Sklivvz What was wrong with the image?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell it was an ad, but it didn't add to the question because it was not the ad in question! :-P There's a "99%" ad which would be relevant, but the ad you put in was just a random Coca-Cola ad.

Comment: @Sklivvz Hmm, are you able to find any ad that actually makes the 99% claim? Every article I have found on the topic used the "Sparkling or sparkling" ad while mentioning the 99% claim.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell from the Freakanomics link: `All of which explains the new print ad I saw for Diet Coke, which was simply a picture of a can of Diet Coke and the words “99 Percent Water.”`

Comment: Maybe we could do a new question: Does the 99% water ad exist? Because - I can't find it, either.

Comment: It's definitely odd, as all articles with that image mention the ad actually stating that it is 99% water, yet no such ad seems to exist. hmm.

Comment: One must also account for the amount of water in the syrup itself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**TL,DR:** Diet cola is 99.8% water. Normal cola is 90% water and (basically) 10% sugar.

The claim is not correct, however in my opinion when someone claims "A is 99% B" they may not mean that literally. In particular the Freakanomics article works with any other ratio in mind - the article is about how claiming that something is mostly water has actually become a good thing and that relates to the price of water.

According to the USDA data:

- Normal cola, contents per 100g

  > Water    g   90.31

  http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4253
- Diet cola, contents per 100g

  > Water    g   99.80

  http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/4166

Some notes:

1. The Coca-Cola company sells [syrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca-Cola_formula#Formula_variations_in_the_United_States) which is then diluted in order to make the beverage. The dilution varies on a case-by-case basis, within some acceptable parameters. See for example here for a [suggested soda fountain setting](http://www.cokepubandbar.co.uk/cola-factory-maintenance.html). This means that the percentage of water is variable, depending on the sample.
2. There is a big difference between 99% and 99.8% of water. There is five times more syrup (or "taste") in a 99% dilution than in a 99.8% dilution . 99% means 1g every 100g of liquid; 99.8% means 1g every 500g.
3. The USDA data is meant to be a standard reference - you can check the links above - given they provide 4 significant digits in the measurement, I doubt that there's more than 1% error in the values. This would include making sure the sample is representative.

Comment: As a side note (or homework left to the reader), you can also do your chemistry calculations based on [syrup composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coca-Cola_formula#Formula_variations_in_the_United_States) and [dilution ratio](http://www.cokepubandbar.co.uk/cola-factory-maintenance.html). I trust the chemists of USDA to give a more precise result, though, hence the comment.

Comment: Diet cola is 99.8% water would indicate that the claim is indeed correct, right?

Comment: @ste It would indicate that it's off by 0.8%.

Comment: I understand that as meaning at least 99% but not 100%.

Comment: @Stefan I agree, and in fact I specifically say "in my opinion when someone claims "A is 99% B" they may not mean that literally"

Comment: @Skliwz Ok that makes sense ;)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Is it possible Diet Coke specifically is 99% water as opposed to 99.8%?

Comment: @SonnyOrdell I've clarified and included your doubt above.

Comment: You seem to be making assumption that syrup is 0% water. Given that it's syrup, rather than powder, wouldn't it need at least some water?

Comment: Given that the human body averages about 65% water, I think an apparently high water percentage in anything is not as dramatic as it may seem.